# Render react component, based from other file option

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-component

I have a `templates.js` file where i set values manually:

```
export const galleries = [{name:'default'},{name:'carousel'},{name:'grid',set:true}];
```

If object contain `{set:true}` I want to render a specific component on `product.js` page.

I was thinking at:

```
const gallery = galleries.find(gallery=>gallery.set==true).name
```

then render:

```
<div>
  gallery == "grid" ? (
    <Grid />
  ) : gallery == "carousel" ? (
    <Carousel />
  ) : (
    <Default />
  )
</div>
```

But it's a little messy...

Is there a better aproach or is there already a package that did this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const Component = {
    grid: <Grid />,
    carousel: <Carousel />,
    default: <Default />
}
```

**Option 1:**

render:

```
<div>
  {Component[gallery]}
</div>
```

**Option 2:**

I recommend you to validate gallery because the find function may returns null:

```
const item = galleries.find(gallery=>gallery.set==true);
const gallery = item ? item.name : "default";
```

then:

```
<div>
  {Component[gallery]}
</div>
```